# How to export minify or uglify javascript library file

Tags: javascript

How can I export minify or uglify javascript library file with module.exports so that I can import that library file in another js file with import statement.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is not compiled in the traditional sense, unlike C and Java.  Ergo - there is no portable "compilation" format.  Libraries are generally exchanged in source code format.

Comment: My answer is correct for the originally-posed question.  The OP has since changed the question.